# F5 load balancer behaves differently without accept-encoding header

Tags: apache-2.2, f5-big-ip

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my F5 load balancer configuration.

I have an Apache instance running behind F5 and when i try to access my website over F5, I get empty response for a few pages.

The same pages work fine when i add a request header "Accept-encoding":"deflate"

I am thinking this issue could be due to some misconfiguration at F5.

Has anyone got an idea what might be the reason for this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your F5's configuration I would suspect you're correct, something is misconfigured within the HTTP compression profile for the virtual server.

BIG-IP will take the accept-encoding header from the client, and inserts a content-encoding header for gzip or deflate determined by the original client request. If the virtual server is not setup for HTTP traffic or does not have an HTTP compression profile I could see you having issues with proxying the accept-encoding and returning the content-encoding header.

My BIG-IP v13 HTTP compression profile defaults to gzip for preferred compression method.

[image]

If your virtual sever has an HTTP profile and not an HTTP compression profile, start by copying the default to a new profile and toggling this. If you're BIG-IP is older than v11, this field is in the HTTP profile. Give this a whirl and see what happens.

Check out [F5 KB15434](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K15434) for more information on this and if all else fails, [DevCentral Q&A](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/re-compressing-a-response-after-removing-accept-encoding-in-an-irule) may have some more details on this.

Comment: Thanks, It was solved by tuning some F5 settings. The F5 had a security restriction of gzip compressed content types

Comment: Oh yea... that would definitely do it.  Glad you got it all worked out.